# creating record with nested attributes in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following 2 models.

```
class Expression < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :patterns, :foreign_key => "PTN_EXPRESSION_FK", :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :patterns, :allow_destroy => true

end



class Pattern < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :expression, :foreign_key => :PTN_EXPRESSION_FK

end
```

I would like to create a record (with nested attributes) and store it in the tables without using a form.

```
Expression.create(:EXP_VALUE  =>  @exp.val,
          :EXP_ADD_VALUE =>  @exp.add_val    
          )
```

The code above create an expression record and save it in the Expression table.

I would also like to pass the pattern value to the above code so that the pattern values are stored in the pattern table at the same time expression is stored.

How do I pass the nested attributes values in the 'create' code above?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The nested attributes could be like this:

```
Expression.create(:EXP_VALUE  =>  @exp.val,
      :EXP_ADD_VALUE =>  @exp.add_val,
      :patterns_attributes => [
        '0' => {:pattern_attr1 => ..., pattern_attr2 => ..., ...},
        '1' => {:pattern_attr1 => ..., pattern_attr2 => ..., ...},
        '2' => {:pattern_attr1 => ..., pattern_attr2 => ..., ...},
        ...
       ]
    )
```